# Deserialize json object after authentication in webapi

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm sending a post request to webapi 2.0 "www.someurl.com\token" as follows -

```
"username": "someone@gmail.com", "password": "somepassword", "grant_type" : "password"
```

If the webapi can authenticate it sends me a bearer token that has this fields -

```
"{\"access_token\":\"...the token...\",\"token_type\":\"bearer\",\"expires_in\":1209599,\"userName\":\"someone@gmail.com\",\".issued\":\"Mon, 05 Nov 2018 13:59:10 GMT\",\".expires\":\"Mon, 19 Nov 2018 13:59:10 GMT\"}"
```

I was wondering if I can deserialize it to a class object directly something may be like this `Json.Convert<Object Type>(data)`. I can always use a custom object to do it but I'm searching if I can use some standard class type.

Comment: I'd suggest writing your own type with the properties that you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ask yourself: what you want to use this object for? Just deserializing to an object will mean that you don't get access to any of the properties without the use of reflection, which will be messy at best. Instead, declare a class:

```
public sealed class BearerToken
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresInMilliseconds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userName")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = ".issued")]
    public DateTimeOffset? IssuedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = ".expires")]
    public DateTimeOffset? ExpiresOn { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BearerToken>(data);` which will give you a fully-formed `BearerToken` object which you can then use.

Note that the magic here is in the `JsonProperty` attribute which will inform the converter as to which field goes where. You could also use tools like [this](http://json2csharp.com/) to auto-generate classes for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in .NET library for OAuth. Normally, identity providers (IDP) provide those strongly-typed libraries.

For example, Azure AD provides [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectMessage.cs).

```
namespace Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
{  
  public class OpenIdConnectMessage : AuthenticationProtocolMessage
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets 'access_Token'.
    /// </summary>
    public string AccessToken ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets 'token_type'.
    /// </summary>
    public string TokenType ...

     /// <summary>
     /// Gets or sets 'expires_in'.
     /// </summary>
     public string ExpiresIn ...
  }
}
```

Comment: If i use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenIdConnectMessage>(responseData)` it gets user name and type of the token `Bearer` but actual token and rest of the information is null. I tried to parse it after converting it inot a JsonObject `JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(resp)` and then `OpenIdConnectMessage responseData = new OpenIdConnectMessage(jobj)` then I get the actual token and `expire_in` values and rest are missing as well. I believe using a custom object is far better idea.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can do so by declaring the variable you try to deserialize to `dynamic`

Try this:

```
dynamic value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>("");
```

You will need the Newtonsoft.Json Nuget Package

Now you can access the values simply by:

```
Console.Writeline(value.username);
```

Edit: This probably won't work because there are properties that start with a '.'

Comment: Every time someone uses `dynamic`, a kitten dies. There's no need in 99% of the times it is suggested, and this is no difference...

Comment: There are two fields that starts with a dot ".issued" and ".expires" that annoys me to use your proposed method, I think it will not recognize the extra dot before the name, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes i guess you are right. Both of you. It's dirty and in this specific case it probably won't work.